# Twig Template print field - if not node number

Tags: theming

I can print an image field in my node template like this:

```
{{ content.field_big_image }}
```

But can I say "print this field but not if the node number is node/45" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Sometimes themes will drop documentation when they override a template, but you can always check the original template file for the available variables and other info relevant for working with the template. If you check the *node.html.twig* template provided by the node module in core, you'll see the following documentation at the top of the file.

```
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a node.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - node: The node entity with limited access to object properties and methods.
 *   Only method names starting with "get", "has", or "is" and a few common
 *   methods such as "id", "label", and "bundle" are available. For example:
 *   - node.getCreatedTime() will return the node creation timestamp.
 *   - node.hasField('field_example') returns TRUE if the node bundle includes
 *     field_example. (This does not indicate the presence of a value in this
 *     field.)
 *   - node.isPublished() will return whether the node is published or not.
 * 
 * ... continued ...
 *
 */
```

Note the relevant info here:

> The node entity [is available] with limited access to object properties and methods. Only method names starting with "get", "has", or "is" and a few common methods such as "id", "label", and "bundle" are available.

This means you can access the node id with `node.id`.

So, you can print your field on nodes other than your specific node by wrapping your field in a conditional like:

```
{% if node.id != 45 %}
  {{ content.field_big_image }}
{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% if not node.id == 45 %}
  {{ content.field_big_image }}
{% endif %}
```

Either choice should produce the same result.

Comment: or {% if not (node.id == 45) %}